# Where to put user defined strings in an HID device?

Tags: usb, stm32, hid

I have an HID device and I'm trying to add two pieces of information to be read out over USB. First, I want to be able to read a firmware version string that I create at compile time. Second I want to be able to set the role of the device using two jumpers and send out a 0,1,2,3. The first half of each of these is working fine, I'm now stuck at where exactly I should place this information to be able to read it on the host end.

I've considered adding it as a data type like a button or similar but this feels very hacky. I've also considered changing the PID or Product string but these feel like they should remain constant across firmware updates. My current though is to add a custom string to the Device descriptor.

```
const uint8_t USBD_DeviceDesc[USB_SIZ_DEVICE_DESC] =
{
  0x12,                       /*bLength */
  USB_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE, /*bDescriptorType*/
  0x00,                       /*bcdUSB */
  0x02,
  0x00,                       /*bDeviceClass*/
  0x00,                       /*bDeviceSubClass*/
  0x00,                       /*bDeviceProtocol*/
  USB_MAX_EP0_SIZE,           /*bMaxPacketSize*/
  LOBYTE(USBD_VID),           /*idVendor*/
  HIBYTE(USBD_VID),           /*idVendor*/
  LOBYTE(USBD_PID),           /*idProduct*/
  HIBYTE(USBD_PID),           /*idProduct*/
  0x00,                       /*bcdDevice fw revision */
  0x01,
  USBD_IDX_MFC_STR,           /*Index of manufacturer  string*/
  USBD_IDX_PRODUCT_STR,       /*Index of product string*/
  USBD_IDX_SERIAL_STR,        /*Index of serial number string*/
  USBD_CFG_MAX_NUM            /*bNumConfigurations*/
} ; /* USB_DeviceDescriptor */
```

And then I would I add something like:

```
  USBD_IDX_USR_STR            /*Index of custom user string*/
```

Would this be acceptable? And if so, how do I let the host know what this new byte in the device descriptor means? Is there a meta descriptor of some sort that defines the byte offsets of each piece of the device descriptor?

If this is not acceptable, where should I put a string like the firmware version or role?

Answer (score 0):

It is not acceptable to add data to the USB Device Descriptor because the size and structure of it is defined in the USB specifications.

It is fine for you to have your device return some custom strings in response to "Get String Descriptor" requests with the right index though.  Normal USB drivers will only request the drings that are referred to in your device/interface/configuration descriptors anyway, so they will never see the extra string that you want to add.  A string descriptor would be a good way to implement the firmware version string.  (You should also put firmware version information in bcdDevice, by the way.)  You would choose an index number for the string and then hard-code that number in whatever software needs to read it; there is no reason to try to force that number into a descriptor somewhere.

You could perhaps use jumpers to set the "role" of your device, but jumpers are kind of like keys, or buttons, so I would suggest that you report them in some standard way using the HID protocol.  Maybe you should ask about them in a separate question.